# Nativescript Tutorial: error with livesync

Tags: nativescript

I'm running on macosx with nativscript 2.0 (typescript+angular2 tutorial).
I just ran the `tns run ios --emulator` command and then ctrl-c.

Then running this command: tns livesync ios --emulator --watch

results in:

```
.
.
.
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all project files.
Applying changes...
**Error Command failed: killall sampleGroceries2.app
No matching processes belonging to you were found
 while executing killall sampleGroceries2.app.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the [{N} + Angular2 tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html) and afer following the instruction I had no problems with the livesync option.

Have you updated to NativeScript 2.0.0 - I have noticed that this error was logged in the previous version 1.7.1.
If you need to update your NativeScript version globally you can run

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

After that step you can remove/add the platform folder from your project with the following commands

```
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios
```

Also delete the node_modules folder and the re-run

```
tns run ios --emulator
```

To check your current NativeScript version you can execute

```
tns --version
```

The latest official release of {N} has some livesync fixes so now your command should run as espected - let us know if that solution was appliable for your case.